# День добрый, вопрос по форме отправки данных в частности файлов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть  форма: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При её открытии она выглядит вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При клике на добавить файл:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После добавления файла - старая кнопка прячется  и на место её становится новая.
Теперь к сути проблемы:
В гугл Хром весь код выполняется валидно - данные отправляются хорошо, не дублируются.
Но при отправке данных через мозила фаерфокс, файл отправляется каким-то образом 2 раза, для отправки данных с формы я пользуюсь следующим кодом:

```
    "use strict";
    $("#form_client_data_value").validate({
    debug: false,
    onfocusout: false,
    onKeyUp: true,
    submitHandler: function (form) {
    if ($(form).find('input[type=file]').length > 0) {
        $(form).append("<iframe src='#' id='upload_frame'      name='upload_frame' style='opacity: 0; width: 0; height: 0; border: 0;'></iframe>")
            .attr("enctype", "multipart/form-data")
            .attr("method", "POST")
            .attr("file", "true")
            .attr("target", "upload_frame");
        form.submit();
        $("#end_document_download").modal('show');
    }
}
    });

    $("button[data_user_check]").on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
    url: $("#form_client_data_value").attr('action'),
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    success: function (html) {
        var contents = $(html).find("#content_user_replace");
        $("#content").html($(contents));
    }
        });
        $("#end_document_download").modal('hide');

    });
```

Еще есть такая проблема что Замена файла, тоже является инпутом и при перед отправкой данных при копировании формы в `iframe` - копируется вся форма, т. е. все инпуты, включая инпуты для замены файла, но отсылаются разумеется только  файлы которые прикрепил пользователь  под добавить файл, можно ли как-то облегчить задачу отправки файлов, что нужно для этого сделать, можно как-то сделать так чтобы брались только инпут тайп файлы от "Добавить файлы", я в js,jq новенький, прошу сильно не пинать и рассказать все доступно и понятно, чтобы не возникало вопросов по структуре html я вставляю на пастербин часть html отвечающую за форму

[Ссылка на код](http://pastebin.com/raw/HD05czJn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо приостановить первую отправку формы, которая происходит после вызова функции submitHandler.

В конец функции submitHandler добавьте `return false;`

Источник - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798717/preventing-a-form-from-submitting-in-jquery-validate-plugins-submithandler-func.

Либо если, форма 2 раза отправляется через iframe, то просто уберите эту строку `form.submit();`